# Answering machine with Android Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, phone-call

Is it possible to create an answering machine with Titanium on Andorid?
If yes, is there a module that can detect incoming calls even if the app is closed?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's technically [impossible](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/yBE9inbf1Z4) to make an answering machine for Android because the operating system does not allow apps to access the in-call audio stream.

Comment: Is this still the case? Has this changed?